# Magento: Building a store URL in CMS-syntax, using a variable

Tags: templates, magento

I am building an e-mail template. I want to build a URL like this:

```
http://store.com/path/to/page?shipmentid=123
```

This code builds the correct URL:

```
{{store url='path/to/page' _query_shipmentid=123}}
```

But the `123` part should be dynamic. I need it to pull from this variable:

```
{{var shipment.id}}
```

Is this even possible? I'm looking for something like this:

```
{{store url='path/to/page' _query_shipmentid=shipment.id}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$` prefix to let Magento know that it is variable. This code should work:

```
{{store url='path/to/page' _query_shipmentid=$shipment.getId()}}
```